# Bootstrap Carousel Toggleable / Dynamic Tabs

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

i try to do in every tab an Picture Gallery (Home, Menu1, Menu2, Menu3) , in the first tab it works but in the other tab(Menu1) it won´t work. It start the gallery but cant switch with the selektor icons. Have anybody an idea?                                                                              .

```css
  .carousel-inner > .item > img,
  .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
    width: 70%;
    margin: auto;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Toggle</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>

  </style>
    </head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Dynamic Tabs</h2>
  <p>To make the tabs toggleable, add the data-toggle="tab" attribute to each link. Then add a .tab-pane class with a unique ID for every tab and wrap them inside a div element with class .tab-content.</p>

  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

      <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_chania.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Chania</h3>
          <p>The atmosphere in Chania has a touch of Florence and Venice.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_chania2.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Chania</h3>
          <p>The atmosphere in Chania has a touch of Florence and Venice.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_flower.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Flowers</h3>
          <p>Beautiful flowers in Kolymbari, Crete.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_flower2.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Flowers</h3>
          <p>Beautiful flowers in Kolymbari, Crete.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
  
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

      <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_chania.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Chania</h3>
          <p>The atmosphere in Chania has a touch of Florence and Venice.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_chania2.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Chania</h3>
          <p>The atmosphere in Chania has a touch of Florence and Venice.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_flower.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Flowers</h3>
          <p>Beautiful flowers in Kolymbari, Crete.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_flower2.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Flowers</h3>
          <p>Beautiful flowers in Kolymbari, Crete.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
  
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 3</h3>
      <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added same id on both careousel selector that's why it wasn't working in another tab. here is the working solution:

```css
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
  .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
    width: 70%;
    margin: auto;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Toggle</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>

  </style>
    </head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Dynamic Tabs</h2>
  <p>To make the tabs toggleable, add the data-toggle="tab" attribute to each link. Then add a .tab-pane class with a unique ID for every tab and wrap them inside a div element with class .tab-content.</p>

  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

      <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_chania.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Chania</h3>
          <p>The atmosphere in Chania has a touch of Florence and Venice.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_chania2.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Chania</h3>
          <p>The atmosphere in Chania has a touch of Florence and Venice.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_flower.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Flowers</h3>
          <p>Beautiful flowers in Kolymbari, Crete.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_flower2.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Flowers</h3>
          <p>Beautiful flowers in Kolymbari, Crete.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
  
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <div id="myCarousel1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel1" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel1" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel1" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel1" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

      <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_chania.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Chania</h3>
          <p>The atmosphere in Chania has a touch of Florence and Venice.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_chania2.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Chania</h3>
          <p>The atmosphere in Chania has a touch of Florence and Venice.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_flower.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Flowers</h3>
          <p>Beautiful flowers in Kolymbari, Crete.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_flower2.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Flowers</h3>
          <p>Beautiful flowers in Kolymbari, Crete.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
  
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel1" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel1" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 3</h3>
      <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you verry much!

Comment: Glad to help you. If it works, please accpet this as an answer so it will be helpful for others who might face same situation. happy coding.!